# Replace one digit numbers (1 or 5B) in a string with two digits (01 or 05B)

Tags: r, regex, gsub

Assume the following vector of characters with an inconsistent number format:

```
myvec <- c( '50% of population live in block 50 number 27-04', 
'And 1% of population live in block 8 number 1-42', 
'And 1% of population live in block 5B number 1-8', 
'60% of population live in block 1641 number 17-23',
'80% of population live in block 677B number 5-3')
```

I want to have a consistent number format such that every number has at least two digits:

```
c( '50% of population live in block 50 number 27-04', 
'And 01% of population live in block 08 number 01-42', 
'And 01% of population live in block 05B number 01-08', 
'60% of population live in block 1641 number 17-23',
'80% of population live in block 677B number 05-03')
```

If it is easier to get all numbers to 4 digits (max. number of digits) that would also be ok:

```
c( '0050% of population live in block 0050 number 0027-0004', 
'And 0001% of population live in block 0008 number 0001-0042', 
'And 0001% of population live in block 0005B number 0001-0008', 
'0060% of population live in block 1641 number 0017-0023',
'0080% of population live in block 0677B number 0005-0003')
```

Important is that all numbers with the same number of digits follow the same format. In the end I want to read out the block and number (e.g. 'block 50 number 27-04') and check for duplicates (the actual vector is much longer and consists of duplicates in block and number but with different text before that) - which I cannot at the moment as the beginning of the string might differ.

I tried several things like `gsub("(\\d)+", "0\\1", myvec)` but they didn't work out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `stringr::str_replace_all` to replace all the numbers in the string as 4-digit number.

```
stringr::str_replace_all(myvec, "\\d+", function(m) sprintf("%04s", m))
#[1] "0050% of population live in block 0050 number 0027-0004"     
#[2] "And 0001% of population live in block 0008 number 0001-0042" 
#[3] "And 0001% of population live in block 0005B number 0001-0008"
#[4] "0060% of population live in block 1641 number 0017-0023"     
#[5] "0080% of population live in block 0677B number 0005-0003"
```

You can replace `"%04s"` part in `sprintf` with number of digits you need in your output.

---

For some reason `%04s` works only for me. We can use `%04d` as suggested by @Jaap after converting the extracted part to integers.

```
stringr::str_replace_all(myvec, "\\d+", function(m) sprintf("%04d", as.integer(m)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When I copy-paste your command it inserts the respective number of spaces not zeros. I also started a new R session to see whether some option I changed might have caused it but it inserted spaces again. Technically, that would solve my problem of comparing the block and number as well but I'm quiet puzzled why I get a different outcome.

Comment: @sh_student that's weird. I restarted my R session as well to check if there was something else that was causing it but it works for me the same way on fresh R session as well. Can you try `sprintf("%04d", m))` instead of `%04s` ? Using `%04d` returns error to me but you can try and see if you get any different output? Lastly we can check R.version and `stringr` package version. My R.version is 3.6.1 and `stringr` is `1.4.0`

Comment: Inserting `sprintf("%04d", m))` returns the error `invalid format '%04d'; use format %s for character objects`. My R version is 3.6.0 and the stringr version is 1.4.0. I will update my R version and see whether I will get a different outcome.

Comment: I updated my R version but still get the same outcome with spaces instead of zeros

Comment: Are you using the same `myvec` as you have posted in the question ?

Comment: Yes, I copied `myvec` from my question in the console

Comment: I think it should be `stringr::str_replace_all(myvec, "\\d+", function(m) sprintf("%04d", as.integer(m)))`

Comment: @sh_student Can you try the above posted by Jaap? It should work now.